# Is it possible to force facebook password entry on adding application

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-authentication, facebook-apps

I want to ensure that the app I am working on is added to the correct FB account. More specifically, I want to ensure that it is not erroneously added to the account of a user who may have been previously using the browser.

A user first comes to my app via an email link. In some cases, the browser they are using may have an active session for a FB user who was previously using the browser. FB will ask if they want to grant access to my app, but it could be for the previous user and the current user might not recognize this.

An obvious solution is to only permit a user to add my app if they can correctly enter their FB credentials - is it possible to do this - only allow a user to add an app if the user enters their credentials correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Yup. You need this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reauthentication/ :)

Comment: +1, the reauthentication step is designed specifically for this use-case